# How to test if an id is present in an associative array

Tags: javascript

I'm am starting in javascript. I'm trying to do a little program that make a statistic upon the number of answer found in a text document.

The situation is this: each question has one id, e.g `8000001` and `W` if answer is good or `R` if answer is not good, e.g for an user answer is `8000001W`. I have many user so many question of the same id. I want to get number of good answers per questions. E.g id: 800001 have `W: 24 and "R": 5`.

I have split the answer into `id` for `8000001` and `ans` for `W` or `R`. I wanted to create an associative table to get `question[id]=["W": 0, "R": 0]`. But I'm blocking on this. I've tried this code:

```
var tab = [];
tab[0] = [];
tab[0] = ['8000001W', '8000002W', '8000003W', '8000004R', '8000005W', '8000006R'];
tab[1] = [];          
tab[1] = ['8000001R', '8000002W', '8000003R', '8000004W', '8000005R', '8000006W'];
var question = [];
var id;


for (var i=0;i<tab.length;i++) {
      document.write("<dl><dt>tableau n° "+i+"<\/dt>");
      for (var propriete in tab[i]) {
      id = tab[i][propriete].slice(0,7);
      var ans = tab[i][propriete].slice(7,8); 
      question[id] = [];
      if(question[id]){
          incrementResp.call(rep, ans);
      }else{
          var rep = initResp(ans);
          question[id] = rep; 
      }    
  }
  document.write("<\/dl>");
}

function incrementResp(type){
    this.this++;
}
function initResp(t){
    rep = [];
    rep.W = (t=='W'?1:0);
    rep.R = (t=='R'?1:0);
}
```

Comment: What's up with the `<blink>` tag?

Comment: excuse it was for stackoverflow. It's not in my code

Comment: not sure what you're asking, but try using generic objects {}, you can check if a property exists with `if(tab['id']){
/*do something*/
}`

Comment: i just wanted to test whether the id have a response if yes i increment if no a create a response for this id

Comment: e.g rep = ["W": 0, "R": 0]; question[id] = rep;

Comment: Could you explain your code a little bit more? I couldn't get much of it. if(question[id]) will always be true because you are assigning a value to it.

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to check if the key id is present in question?

Comment: There are no associative arrays in javascript. You probably want an object: `{R: 0, W: 0}`.

Comment: http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Comment: my code so if for example 800001 has resp then i increment value "W" or "R" but if 800001 has no-resp then a create resp.

Comment: i want to get that result id question 8000001 response "W"=1 and reponse "R"=1

Comment: My goal is to count the number of good and false ansewer per question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what your want finally, the 'question' should be used as an object literal, defined as `question = {}` (similar to association array), what you defined here is an array literal. You can check this for more information about different types of literals in JavaScript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Literals

In terms of your code, you can simple do like this:

```
if (question[id]) {
    question[id][ans] += 1;
}
else {
    var rep = initResp(ans);
    question[id] = rep;
}
```

Also your 'initResp' function better to return an object literal 'rep', not as an array literal:

```
function initResp(t){
    var rep = {};
    rep.W = (t=='W'?1:0);
    rep.R = (t=='R'?1:0);
    return rep;
}
```

Comment: `if (question[id]) {` should be `if (id in question) {` because `{}` is evaluated to `true`. See `if ({}) console.log("a");`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But in this particular case, we never end up with `question[id]={}`, it is either `question[id]={W:0, R:0}` or `question[id]=undefined`.

Comment: Then, you can delete the `else` block and the `initResp` function. You should edit `question[id]={W:0, R:0}` into your answer.

Comment: Well, I think we could get rid of 'initResp' function, since it simply create an new object literal `{W:0, R:1}` based on whether the last character is 'W' or 'R'. But `else` block should be kept in case the question object doesn't contain the new 'id'

Comment: @Artjom B I think I know why you said `else` can be removed. The code snippet I gave here is not complete, the `if..else` is wrapped by a nested loop. So `question` object is actually dynamically built. How many elements in `question` object depends on how many iterations we have

Comment: Great wpding i have solve my problems. i will put the code below

Comment: @rodolphe good to know it helps. If the answer is what you are looking for, could you please accept it? :)

Answer (score 0):

For an "associative array" in JavaScript, use a regular object.  In the code below, "results" is one of these objects.  It has two keys, "W" and "R" that point to numbers starting at 0.  Just iterate through your answer arrays and continuously increment the correct key.

There are two ways to access a key in an object:  1) using brackets, 2) using "dot" notation.  In the loop I use brackets because 'key' is a variable--it will resolve to "W" or "R" and therefore access the "W" or "R" key in that object.  In the final two lines I use dot notation because "W" and "R" are literally the keys I want to access.  It would also work if I did this instead:  `results['W']++` and `results['R']++`.

```
var tab = [];
tab[0] = ['8000001W', '8000002W', '8000003W', '8000004R', '8000005W', '8000006R'];       
tab[1] = ['8000001R', '8000002W', '8000003R', '8000004W', '8000005R', '8000006W'];

var results = {
  W: 0,
  R: 0
};

// go through each tab
for (var tabIdx = 0; tabIdx < tab.length; tabIdx++) {

  // go through each answer and apppend to an object that keeps the results
  for (var i = 0; i < tab[tabIdx].length; i++) {
    var answer = tab[tabIdx][i];

    // the last character in the string is the "key", (W or R)
    var key = answer.slice(-1);

    // append to the results object
    results[key]++;
  }
}

console.log(results);

console.log(results.W);   // 7
console.log(results.R);   // 5
```

Open up your development console (on Chrome it's F12) to see the output.

Comment: This i have done it. But my problem i didn't want to get the total of all "W" and "R". But the totat per question. e.g 800001R, 800001W, 800001R, 800001W, 800001W the result would be 800001 R=2 and W=3

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer.  Now the values are numbers that start at zero, and are incremented in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i resolved my problem for associative array.

```
var tab = [];
tab[0] = ['8000001W', '8000002W', '8000003W', '8000004R', '8000005W', '8000006R'];       
tab[1] = ['8000001R', '8000002W', '8000003R', '8000004W', '8000005R', '8000006W'];
tab[2] = ['8000001R', '8000002W', '8000003R', '8000004W', '8000005R', '8000006W'];
var question = {};


for (var tabIndex = 0; tabIndex < tab.length; tabIndex++) {


  for (var i = 0; i < tab[tabIndex].length; i++) {
    var answer = tab[tabIndex][i];

    var id = answer.slice(0,7);
    var ans = answer.slice(-1);

    if (question[id]) {
      question[id][ans] += 1;
     }else {
        var results = initResp(ans);
        question[id] = results;
       }

  }
}
console.log(question);


function initResp(t) {
    var results = [];
    results.W = (t === 'W' ? 1 : 0);
    results.R = (t === 'R' ? 1 : 0);
    //console.log(results);
    return results;
}
```